# Numeric output is all zeros?

Tags: c#

I want to read in a file with data from a census. From this data I need to output how many people live in a given district and how many people are within a certain age group.

The problem is my output is showing all zeros, except for the "Age Under 18" line which is showing 100. For reference, the file being read in has 100 people, and 22 districts.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream("censusdata.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(fStream);

        string input = "";
        int age = 0;
        int district = 0;
        const int AGE = 5;
        const int DISTRICT = 22;
        string[] fields;
        bool ageBool = true;
        bool distBool = true;
        int[] ageCount = new int[AGE];
        int[] ageRange = new int[AGE] { 0, 18, 30, 45, 64 };
        int[] districtCount = new int[DISTRICT];
        int[] districtRange = new int[DISTRICT];

        input = inFile.ReadLine();
        while(input != null)
        {
            fields = input.Split(',');
            input = inFile.ReadLine();

            if (ageBool)
            {
                validDataAge(fields, input, age, ageBool);
                getValuePerAge(age, ageCount, ageRange);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("error");

            if (distBool)
            {
                validDataDistrict(fields, input, district, distBool);
                getValuePerDistrict(district, districtCount, districtRange);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("error");
        }
        displayOutput(districtCount, ageCount);
    }

    static bool validDataAge(string[] fieldsArray, string inputData, int a, bool age)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(fieldsArray[0], out a))
        {
            age = true;
            return age;
        }
        else
        {
            age = false;
            return age;
        }
    }

    static bool validDataDistrict(string[] fieldsArray, string inputData, int d, bool district)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(fieldsArray[3], out d))
        {
            district = true;
            return district;
        }
        else
        {
            district = false;
            return district;
        }
    }

    static void getValuePerDistrict(int d, int[] districtCountArray, int[] districtRangeArray)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= districtRangeArray.Length; x++)
        {
            if (x == d)
                districtCountArray[x]++;
        }

    }

    static void getValuePerAge(int a, int[] ageCountArray, int[] ageRangeArray)
    {
        int index = ageRangeArray.Length - 1;
        while(a < ageRangeArray[index])
            index--;


        ageCountArray[index]++;
    }

    public static void displayOutput(int[] districtCountArray, int[] ageCountArray)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < districtCountArray.Length; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("District " + (x + 1) + ": Population = " + districtCountArray[x]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");


        Console.WriteLine("Age Under 18: Population = " + ageCountArray[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Ages 18-30: Population = " + ageCountArray[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Ages 31-45: Population = " + ageCountArray[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("Ages 46-64: Population = " + ageCountArray[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("65 & Over: Population = " + ageCountArray[4]);

    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
District 1: Population = 0
District 2: Population = 0
District 3: Population = 0
District 4: Population = 0
District 5: Population = 0
District 6: Population = 0
District 7: Population = 0
District 8: Population = 0
District 9: Population = 0
District 10: Population = 0
District 11: Population = 0
District 12: Population = 0
District 13: Population = 0
District 14: Population = 0
District 15: Population = 0
District 16: Population = 0
District 17: Population = 0
District 18: Population = 0
District 19: Population = 0
District 20: Population = 0
District 21: Population = 0
District 22: Population = 0




Age Under 18: Population = 100
Ages 18-30: Population = 0
Ages 31-45: Population = 0
Ages 46-64: Population = 0
65 & Over: Population = 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: And where is the `censusdata.txt`>

Comment: It is saved in the debug folder of my project. Basically it looks like this:

Comment: 72, M, S, 10
.. 72 being the age, 10 being the District

Comment: Did you debug the code and check which line of code is not working as per your logic? Where do you think can be a problem?

Comment: `districtRange` is empty all the time, so the loop will never be run and the inside code will never update the array `districtCount`, also that array is always empty. Your code is so messy, in real world app we don't use arrays like this, just use `List` and its performance is good enough to suit almost scenarios. Not mentioned that your way to calculate the districtCount is wrong. Counting something is just like grouping all before obtaining count of each group (or already have the count while grouping). So a Dictionary should be used.

Comment: Sorry for it being messy, I'm fairly new to coding. And I would use List but we're not allowed to use code we haven't learned in the class.

Comment: Most your function parameters are pass by value, for example agebool or districtbool so they always have value true and not change in function, can you check it ?

Comment: The error is on this line :  validDataAge(fields, input, age, ageBool);  age is being passed out so you need :  validDataAge(fields, input, out age, ageBool);  You also need to change following : static bool validDataAge(string[] fieldsArray, string inputData, out int a, bool age)

Comment: You're a life saver jdweng, thank you so much.

Comment: For a student, this is very good code. Keep studying, you've got talent.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `int a` to be `out int a` in your `validDataAge` method:

```
static bool validDataAge(string[] fieldsArray, string inputData, out int a, bool age)
{
    if (int.TryParse(fieldsArray[0], out a))
    {
        age = true;
        return age;
    }
    else
    {
        age = false;
        return age;
    }
}
```

But, just as a further suggestion, that method can be written as:

```
static bool validDataAge(string inputData, out int a)
{
    return int.TryParse(inputData, out a);
}
```

But then, `validDataAge` is basically the same function as `int.TryParse` so you could remove `validDataAge` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

What you have shows promise; it's a good student beginner effort. I don't know how much of this you will understand, but I wanted you to at least get a chance to see something closer to how this could look, to help you develop good habits.

```
public class CensusRecord
{
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public int DistrictID {get;set;}
    public bool DataReady {get;private set;}

    public static CensusRecord FromDataLine(string line)
    {
       // I don't normally recommend .Split() for CSV data -- too many edge cases
       //  -- but this didn't seem like the time to pull in a CSV reader
       var fields = line.Split(','); 
       int age = 0, district = 0;

       var result = new CensusRecord();
       result.DataReady = true;

       if (int.TryParse(fieldsArray[0], out age))
           result.Age = age;
       else
           result.DataReady = false;

       if (int.TryParse(fieldsArray[3], out district))
           result.DistrictID = district;
       else
           result.DataReady = false;

        return result;          
    }
}

class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<CensusRecord> LoadData(string filename)
    {
        return File.ReadLines(filename)
             .Select(line => CensusRecord.FromDataLine(line))
             .Where(r => r.DataReady);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = LoadData("censusdata.txt").ToList();

        DisplayDistrictPopulations(data);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        DisplayAgeGroups(data);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void DisplayDistrictPopulations(IEnumerable<CensusRecord> data)
    {
        foreach(var district in data.GroupBy(r => r.DistrictID).OrderBy(g => g.Key))
        {
             Console.WriteLine("District {0}: Population = {1}", district.Key, district.Count());
        }
    }

    static void DisplayAgeGroups(IEnumerable<CensusRecord> data)
    {
        var groups = data.GroupBy(r => {
            if (r.Age <  18) return 0;
            if (r.Age <= 30) return 1;
            if (r.Age <= 45) return 2;
            if (r.Age <= 64) return 3;
            return 4;
          }).OrderBy(g => g.Key);

        string[] ageStrings = {"Age Under 18", "Ages 18-30","Ages 31-45", "Ages 46-64", "65 & Over"};

        foreach (var age in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: Population = {1}", ageStrings[age.Key], age.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do that. A lot of it makes sense to me. I will definitely refer to this from time to time.